# How to extract symbol name from ELF file for a given offset

Tags: gdb, elf, objdump, readelf

I have a hex offset, say `0xcccddd`. Using `gdb info symbol 0xcccddd` I can get the symbol name, e.g. `fn()` in `section_name`.

How can I do this using the **readelf** or **objdump** command, or any other commands without running gdb?

---

**EDIT:**
After using the below command

```
objdump -d --start-address 0xcccddd --stop-address 0xcccdde filename.axf
```

I am getting

```
filename.axf:     file format elf32-little
objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
objdump -d --start-address 0xcccddd --stop-address 0xcccdde
```

> I am getting `objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!`

It looks like you are cross-compiling for ARM using RealView compiler. You need to use `objdump` from the *same* NDK the compiler came from (instead of using host-native `objdump`).

Comment: If i use this I am getting   filename.elf   file format elf32-i386.Is there any other steps i need to do after that

Comment: @Prakrithi If that's *all* you get, then `objdump` didn't recognize the section your `0xcccddd` address is in. In that case, I wouldn't expect GDB `info symbol 0xcccddd` to produce anything useful either. Please edit your question to show *actual* commands you give GDB and `objdump`, and their output.

Comment: I am getting objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN! below filename.elf and file format.Missed that in that comment. Can you pls help . I am using .axf file